# How to secure a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install

Tags: server, hardening, ubuntu

I have a service that's spinning up fresh Ubuntu 16.04 instances onto a VPS (on behalf of users) and would really like to do what I can in terms of putting good privacy and security practices in by default.

This is pre any sort of web server or database install, just the base Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is really broad. Secure against what? Privacy in terms of what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [CIS benchmarks](https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/ubuntu_linux/) provide very clear instructions on what should be made to secure most known systems.

Comment: This was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for - some more googling also led me to this: https://github.com/awailly/cis-ubuntu-ansible - which is the CIS guidelines as an Ansible playbook.

Answer (score 3):

I use centos more then ubuntu but I would   disable ssh password logins and only use ssh keys.  If you must use ssh passwords  install an app called fail2ban which temp bans people trying to brute force.  Also makes sure you dont have any services running you don’t need on the public internet.  only the ones needed. 
use a firewall to make that happen.  I use iptables think ubuntu uses firewalld .. but would have to check.